# Not able to completely hide model in forge viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

I am trying to hide the complete model in forge-viewer, for that I am calling forge visibility API as follows:

`viewer.impl.visibilityManager.setNodeOff(viewer.model.getModelId(),true)`

where viewer is a object of `GUIViewer3D`.

But this is not hidding the complete model, some components in the model are still visible.

I think it is a bug in forge-viewer because if I pass a root node of model to `setNodeOff()` API it has to hide whole model. I am sure that there is only one model loaded in my viewer session.

[Refer this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9ntX.png) for the elements which are still visible after calling `viewer.impl.visibilityManager.setNodeOff(viewer.model.getModelId(),true)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As my goal is to completely hide model from viewer, I achieved this by following:

`viewer.clearSelection();
viewer.model.setAllVisibility(0);
viewer.impl.toggleGhosting(false);
viewer.impl.toggleGroundShadow(false);`

This gives me the required behavior. The elements which I was not able to hide are now hidden through this approach.

Comment: OIC... You were looking for rendering preferences in the Forge-Viewer.  I thought it was related to the DBID mismatch between Forge Viewer (cached SVF) and the GET properties API call.  My mistake !

Comment: Yes, there is still an issue with `dbIds`, but I achieved my requirement by some different approach. If I call `viewer.impl.visibilityManager.setNodeOff(viewer.model.getModelId(),true)` 
then it is clearly noticeable that some elements donot have dbIds assigned to them, therefore I am not able to make then off/hide. Even not able to select or isolate them (elements as shown in attached image).

Comment: Btw. @PravinShinde, you may not need the workaround for too long, the dev team has fixed the dbID issue in staging and will soon deploy it to production.

Comment: Great..!!  @PetrBroz, Could you please put me a mail  or post here once it is deployed to production? Thanks.

Comment: Will do @PravinShinde. Cheers!

Comment: @PravinShinde, the fix is now in production. I've tried translating the model you provided and confirmed that the dbIDs are now all valid.

Comment: Thank you very much @PeterBroz. I will try to do the same with my actual model.

Answer (score 1):

`getModelId()` returns *model IDs*, and the visibility APIs expect *node IDs*. In order to hide the entire model, consider the following:

```
viewer.hide(model.getRootId());
```

Comment: I have tried suggested solution but no effect seen. The elements (as in image) are still visible.
`viewer.model.getModelId()` and `viewer.model.getRootId()` returns same values (in my case).

Comment: A couple of questions: (1) what version of the viewer are you using? (2) do you have your app running somewhere publicly? (3) can you reproduce the problem with other models, or just with this particular one?

Comment: 1. I am using forge-viewer 4.2.*
2. No, the app is under development, not currently running publicly.
3. Yes there is issue with some other models (revit models).

Comment: I have tried to hide each element one by one, as follows:

`var instanceTree=viewer.model.getInstanceTree();
    Object.keys(instanceTree.nodeAccess.dbIdToIndex).forEach(dbId => {
      viewer.impl.visibilityManager.setNodeOff(instanceTree.nodeAccess.dbIdToIndex[dbId],true);
    });`

But I am not getting `dbId` for elements which are visible in attached image, thats why I an not able to hide them or make them off.

Comment: Thanks for the info @PraviNShinde, that sounds like an issue with the translation from RVT files to the internal viewing format. Any chance you could share one of the problematic Revit files with me via email? `forge.help [at] autodesk.com`.

Comment: I need to check this with authorities.
I Will get back to you once checked.
Thanks.

Comment: Hello @Petr_Broz, I have checked with authorities for permission to share the problematic file, But we cannot share the original model file.
We have created another dummy model which reproduces the issue.
You can find it here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1tvAgHd635qRIvrx4lzX63Fzrf0RuNxFW
please request a permission to access the file.

Comment: see my post above for a solution

Answer (score 0):

Could you try something for me...

Could you try adding the header 'x-ads-force':'true' to the POST job request when you are converting the .RVT file?

Here is the documentation on the API request...
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/job-POST/#headers

Then, retrieve the URN and feed it to the Forge Viewer, as before, like this example: 
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-manifest-GET/#example

.

> **So... What's going on?**

When you convert a RVT to a SVF (for the the Forge Viewer), it produces a random set of DBIds.

When you call the GetProperties API, it uses that cached SVF to pull the DBIds and provide you with a result.

Back in August, the GetProperty API engine, was updated.  It produces a different order of DBIds compared to the old converted SVF.

Since the old SVF is cached, even if you submit a new job, it will use the old SVF.

To avoid the old SVF, we need to 'force convert' the RVT to SVF conversion, to flush that cache, so that the new SVF is visible and the Forge Viewer can retrieve it.

Once the Forge Viewer can see the new SVF, it should match the DBIds of the GetProperties API.

Complicated huh?

Let me know if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Thanks for adding efforts to investigate the problem, I understood what you are trying to explain. I have tried to add `'x-ads-force':'true'` header while translating model to `svf` format, But issue still persists, no effect seen after change.

Answer (score 0):

to completely hide the model you can isolate an empty list, which will show the whole model ghosted, then you can turn off ghosting globally

```
viewer.isolate([]);
viewer.setGhosting(false);
```